# Create equalised Histogram with R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a dataset .txt which contains three matrices  each of them represents the RGB values of an Image ! I dont have the image (or any image file)! How can I create the equalized histogram of each of my matrices?  I found the `histeq` fuction but It doesnt seem right  ! 
What I've managed to do is
(This is the first part to show the data)

```
fr<-as.data.frame(table(unlist(r)))
fg<-as.data.frame(table(unlist(g)))
fb<-as.data.frame(table(unlist(b)))

fr1=(fr$Freq*100)/(15*15) fb1=(fb$Freq*100)/(15*15)
fg1=(fg$Freq*100)/(15*15)
fr2=cumsum(fr1) fg2=cumsum(fg1) fb2=cumsum(fb1)

r1<-data.frame(fr,fr1,fr2) names<-c("Values","2","Distribution
   Frequancy %","Cumalnative Distribution Frequency %")
   colnames(r1)<-names r1$Values <- as.numeric(as.character(r1$Values))

g1<-data.frame(fg,fg1,fg2) colnames(g1)<-names g1$Values <-
   as.numeric(as.character(g1$Values))

b1<-data.frame(fb,fb1,fb2) colnames(b1)<-names

b1$Values <- as.numeric(as.character(b1$Values))
```

Thats the first part of my exercise ! Than I had to :

```
hb1<-ggplot(data=b1, aes(b1$Values)) +    geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,
260, by =20), 
                  col="white", 
                  aes(fill=..count..))+    labs(title="Ιστόγραμμα Συχνότητας Μπλε Καναλιού") +   labs(x="Τιμές", y="Συχνότητα")

hb2<-ggplot(data=b1, aes(b1$Values)) +    geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,
260, by =20), 
                  col="white", 
                  aes(y=cumsum(..count..),fill=..count..))+    labs(title="Ιστόγραμμα Συχνότητας Μπλε Καναλιού") +   labs(x="Τιμές")

 hb3<-ggplot(data=b1, aes(histeq(b1$Values))) +   
 geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 260, by =20), 
                  col="white", 
                  aes(fill=..count..))+    labs(title="Ιστόγραμμα Εξίσωσης Μπλε Καναλιού") +   labs(x="Nέες Τιμές")

 # Κόκκινο

 hr1<-ggplot(data=r1, aes(r1$Values)) +    geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,
 260, by =20), 
                  col="white", 
                  aes(fill=..count..))+    scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "lightpink", high = "red")+    labs(title="Ιστόγραμμα Συχνότητας
 Κόκκινου Καναλιού") +   labs(x="Τιμές")

 hr2<-ggplot(data=r1, aes(r1$Values)) +    geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,
 260, by =20), 
                  col="white", 
                  aes(y=cumsum(..count..),fill=..count..))+    scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "lightpink", high = "red")+   
 labs(title="ΑΘροιστικό Ιστόγραμμα Κόκκινου Καναλιού") +  
 labs(x="Τιμές")

 hr3<-ggplot(data=r1, aes(histeq(r1$Values))) +   
 geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 260, by =20), 
                  col="white", 
                  aes(fill=..count..))+    scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "lightpink", high = "red")+    labs(title="Ιστόγραμμα Εξίσωσης
 Κόκκινου Καναλιού") +   labs(x="Νέες Τιμές")

 #Πράσινο

 hg1<-ggplot(data=g1, aes(g1$Values)) +    geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,
 260, by =20), 
                  col="white", 
                  aes(fill=..count..))+    scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "lightgreen", high = "green")+    labs(title="Ιστόγραμμα
 Συχνότητας Πράσινου Καναλιού") +   labs(x="Τιμές")

 hg2<-ggplot(data=g1, aes(g1$Values)) +    geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,
 260, by =20), 
                  col="white", 
                  aes(y=cumsum(..count..),fill=..count..))+   scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "lightgreen", high = "green")+  
 labs(title="Αθροιστικό Ιστόγραμμα Πράσινου Καναλιού") +  
 labs(x="Τιμές")

 hg3<-ggplot(data=g1, aes(histeq(g1$Values))) +   
 geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 260, by =20), 
                  col="white", 
                  aes(fill=..count..))+   scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "lightgreen", high = "green")+   labs(title="Ιστόγραμμα Εξίσωσης
 Πράσινου Καναλιού") +   labs(x="Νέες Τιμές")
```

But this way! Using `histeq` I dont have a matrix but a new array of new values.
I want the new matrices with the values of the equalised histogram though

Comment: I also want to have new matrices with the new values !

Comment: Please provide some reproducible data.

Comment: My Data is a .txt file with 3 15x15 matrices of  values from 0-255